# How to fast delte rows with a foreign key relationship?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I want delete all entries from a table. The Problem is it is really slow.
The reason is that another table is revering to the table I want to clean.
So the database has to check ever single entry of the table who has the foreign key (ca. 36 million). What I did was to drop the foreign delete the entries and than recreated the foreign key. But I don't think this is an elegant solution.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out is really fast if i use an index.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name on childTable (foreignKeyField NULLS FIRST);
```